# sbt 12 custom test directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I am upgrading from sbt 11 to sbt 12.2, we currently have the following project structure:

```
src
  main
    scala/...
  test
    shared
      scala/...
    unit
      scala/...
    integration
      scala/...
    functional
      scala/...
```

When I upgrade to sbt 12, the tests no longer run, we are getting: `No tests to run for unit:test`. Having a look at the sbt 12 documentation, in order for it to work out of the box, we'll need to restructure our folder and package structure for the test sources. However, I wanted to check if there is any thing else we can do first before having to restructure.

Our configs for tests are as follows (only unit tests configs are shown, the other test types have the same configuration):

```
lazy val project = Project(ID, BASE, settings = platformSettings)
.configs(Shared)
.configs(UnitTests)

lazy val Shared = config("shared").extend(Runtime)
lazy val sharedSettings = configure(Shared, "shared")

lazy val UnitTests = config("unit") extend(Shared)
lazy val unitTestSettings = configure(UnitTests, "unit")

private def configure(configuration: Configuration, testType: String) = {
  inConfig(configuration)(Defaults.testSettings) ++ inConfig(configuration)(settingsFor(testType))
}

private def settingsFor(testType: String): Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq (
  sourceDirectory <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "test" / testType),
  testListeners <<= (target in Compile).map({ (target) => Seq(new JUnitXmlTestsListener(target.getAbsolutePath()))}),
  parallelExecution := false
)
```